# Настройка перемещаемых профилей Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, active-directory, profile

Задача примерно такая:

1. Есть ПК на Win8.1, который на данный момент не находится в домене, на ПК профиль локального администратора. Есть свежий Win10 ноутбук. Оба ПК для одного пользователя. Есть доменная сеть с контроллером домена на WS2019. Сеть 100 Mb/s
2. Требуется организовать работу перемещаемого профиля между этими двумя ПК (ввести оба ПК в домен). Желательно, чтобы **текущий профиль** локального админа и стал этим перемещаемым профилем (конвертировать его в доменный), но необязательно. Нужно чтобы перенеслись всякие google chrome пароли и пр., рабочий стол, документы. Однако не должны переноситься настроенные устройства (напр. принтеры)

Почитал про migrating profiles и folder redirection. Большой вопрос встал о скорости подгрузки таких профилей. Также как я понял, мигрирующие профили существуют довольно давно, возможно есть технологии поновее (как user-profile disks, но я так понял это только для RDS-профилей)?
В общем, все пререквизиты в п.1, сама задача в п.2. Нужно хотя-бы какое-то направление мысли, как это лучше сделать.

Comment: Тебе один раз или на постоянку?

Comment: @donRumata нужно постоянное решение. Один раз бы и RDP сошло за правду)

Comment: Ну собсно только перемещаемые профили. В винде на сколько я знаю - больше ничего не придумали.